# Running a script with minicom: unknown command "echo"

Tags: shell-script, serial-port, minicom

I want to run a script on a machine accessible only *via* `minicom`. I tried this:

```bsh
echo 'echo test' >> s.sh
sudo minicom -S s.sh -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

A shell does open, but starts with this error: `script "s.sh" line 1: unknown command "echo"`.

If I type `echo test` in the shell that just opened, it works:

```bsh
user@machine:~$ echo test
test
```

No other command I tried to put in `s.sh` was recognized (`ls`, `ifconfig`...), even though they can be launched from the shell. Why can't they be launched from the script?

Comment: Have you tried putting a shebang at the start of the script? `#!/bin/sh` for example

Comment: @Panki I just tried, I got the same error.

Comment: Hm, did you make sure `sh` is actually located unter `/bin/`?

Comment: I'm not sure `minicom -S` supports execution of *shell* scripts, does it? AFAIK it's for running a sequence of "AT" commands. See for example [Minicom send automate script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24610742/4440445)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @steeldriver [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529535/running-a-script-with-minicom-unknown-command-echo?noredirect=1#comment979975_529535), minicom doesn't seem to accept shell scripts. According to [this man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript), we can run a shell command by writing it after `!`.

I replaced my script's content with

`! echo test`

...and the command `sudo minicom -S s.sh -D /dev/ttyUSB0` works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add shebang at the top of the script `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or whatever your shell is.

`#!/bin/bash
echo test`

Comment: I just added a shebang, ran the same command, and got the same error sadly.

Comment: Can you copy what is there in `s.sh` here? also, what is your interpreter?

Comment: My script contains exactly the code in your answer. My interpreter is bash.